# Best way to read minibatches from a very large BigQuery table?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, training-data

I have a large (>200M rows) BigQuery table that i'd like to read mini-batches from so that I can train a machine learning model. The dataset is too large to fit into memory so I can't read it all in at once, but I want my model to learn from all the data. I also want to avoid issuing too many queries due to network latency since that will slow down the training process. What's the best way to do this in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Felipe's answer works if you're using TF, but if you use pytorch or want something that's a bit more agnostic to your training platform, `faucetml` could work well:

- https://github.com/econti/faucetml

From the example in the docs, if you're training two epochs:

```
fml = get_client(
    datastore="bigquery",
    credential_path="bq_creds.json",
    table_name="my_training_table",
    ds="2020-01-20",
    epochs=2,
    batch_size=1024
    chunk_size=1024 * 10000,
    test_split_percent=20,
)
for epoch in range(2):
    fml.prep_for_epoch()
    batch = fml.get_batch()
    while batch is not None:
        train(batch)
        batch = fml.get_batch()
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you using Tensorflow?

`tfio.bigquery.BigQueryClient` 0.9.0 solves this:

```
read_session(
    parent,
    project_id,
    table_id,
    dataset_id,
    selected_fields,
    output_types=None,
    row_restriction='',
    requested_streams=1
)
```

With

> **requested_streams**: Initial number of streams. If unset or 0, we will provide a value of streams so as to produce reasonable throughput. Must be non-negative. The number of streams may be lower than the requested number, depending on the amount parallelism that is reasonable for the table and the maximum amount of parallelism allowed by the system.

- https://www.tensorflow.org/io/api_docs/python/tfio/bigquery/BigQueryClient

Source code:

- https://github.com/tensorflow/io/tree/master/tensorflow_io/bigquery